# Java Swing mixing panes

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

This seems like a newbie question except that I've been trying to wrap my head around the Swing framework for loong time.

Provided you provide an image, dog.jpg, at least 500 px square, the following code should display the image in a scrollpane.  If it displayed *anything*, I probably wouldn't throw my hands up in despair.  What am I missing?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ScrollSample {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String title = (args.length == 0 ? "JScrollPane Sample" : args[0]);
    new ScrollSample( title ) ;
    }

  public ScrollSample ( String title) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Icon icon = new ImageIcon("dog.jpg");
    JLabel dogLabel = new JLabel(icon);
    dogLabel.setSize( 500, 500 ) ;

    JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane() ;
    layeredPane.add( dogLabel, new Integer( 0 )) ;

    JPanel jp = new JPanel() ;
    jp.add( layeredPane ) ;
    jp.setSize( 500, 500 ) ;

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(jp);

    frame.getContentPane().add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: As always I recommend using [WindowBuilder Pro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/quick_start)

Comment: Can't find anything obviously wrong with your code. Have you put dog.jpg in your project root catalog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set the preferred size for `JLayeredPane` if you are drawing components of larger widths and sizes to it. Especially since you are adding it to a JPanel with default layout. `JLayeredPane`s don't have layout managers by default - so either you manage the bounds or add a preferred layout manager to the layered pane. The simple way would be:

After

```
 JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane() ;
```

add

```
 layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
```

And then maximize your window ( or set your `JFrame`'s size to 600X600) when the app runs.

Read up on : [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Comment: Is the layout manager issue the reason why the intermediate JPanel jp is required? Took me a while to figure that out as well.

Answer (score 4):

- The default layout of a JPanel is a Flowlayout. A FlowLayout shows
  each component at its preferred size and has a 5 pixel border. Use a
  BorderLayout instead (or add the layered pane directly to the scroll pane).
- The default preferred size of a JLayeredPane    is (0, 0). Set a
  preferred size for it.

Answer (score 4):

A Swing GUI should be started on the EDT.  Left as an exercise for the user.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class ScrollSample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        final URL url = new URL("http://pscode.org/media/stromlo2.jpg");
        String title = (args.length == 0 ? "JScrollPane Sample" : args[0]);
        new ScrollSample( title, url ) ;
    }

    public ScrollSample ( String title, URL url) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
        JLabel dogLabel = new JLabel(icon);
        dogLabel.setBounds(0,0,640,480);

        JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane() ;
        layeredPane.add( dogLabel, new Integer( 0 )) ;
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(500, 500) ) ;

        JPanel jp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) ;
        jp.add( layeredPane ) ;

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jp);

        frame.getContentPane().add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
        String title = (args.length == 0 ? "JScrollPane Sample" : args[0]);
        new ScrollSample( title, url ) ;
            }
        });
    }